# has_one or belongs_to for one-to-one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, relationship

I have a model `Page` for text pages on site.

I have a model `Feature` for icons on home page, that may have a link to page. (All in all, I must have field `page_id` in `features` table). But `Page` should not have link to feature.

Should I write

```
class Feat < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :page
end
```

or

```
class Feat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
end
```

?

Question is about only code beauty, it works in all ways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised `has_one` works, it shouldn't. `belongs_to` is for when you have the foreign key (`page_id`) on the table, and is what you want in this case.

This is best described in the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)